# How to synchronize a kernel workqueue thread?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm pretty new to Linux device drivers and kernel. I basically want to synchronize a workque thread (Lets call it A()) with another function (Lets call it B()). My purpose here is to fail B when A is running.

Currently, what I have done is as follows.

```
A(){
  active = true; // a variable shared b/w both A and B
  ...
  ...
  ...
  active = false;
}

B(){
   if(active){
      return -EBUSY
    }
 }
```

Is this the right way to synchronize these 2 functions? Is there any other strategy I should follow?

Comment: It depends on where `B()` is called from (in which context, process or atomic) and how much code each function has. Please share the actual code with us.

Comment: To be exact, A is mmc_recan which is run using workqueue (an hence process context). And B is mmc_suspend_host. Basically I need to avoid B from happening when A is running!

Comment: What is exactly the issue that you have?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want B to wait for availability instead?  That is the more usual kernel approach unless the user-mode app has said it doesn't want to block.

Comment: B already has mechanism to block. But the block is active indefinitely and the only way out I see is to return from B.

Answer (score 1):

for Linux-kernel it's bad code. Try reading about *mutex* and *semaphore*.

http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/05/24/semaphores-in-linux.html?page=5

Comment: `mutex` is only gonna force **B** to wait for **A**. It even can cause dead-lock in that case. It's not simple as this. Please read comments for question.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do so?

**A**: `mmc_rescan()` is defined as `INIT_DELAYED_WORK(&host->detect, mmc_rescan);`

**B**: First line of code in `mmc_suspend_host()` is `cancel_delayed_work(&host->detect);`

So your **A** is canceled in **B**. It was done for a reason, brought by **[this commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7de427d088a967d2173739e21e744921d5496a8b)**.

So what's the reason to replace this cancellation with another synchronization? If you don't have this commit in your kernel, just pull it ([cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)), it probably fixes your problem.

### UPDATE

Please see next commits, they change MMC suspend behavior:

1. [mmc: core: Push common suspend|resume code into each bus_ops](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=74590263384e5d4601de7f0ee2790477578829ea)
2. [mmc: core: Initiate suspend|resume from mmc bus instead of mmc host](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=986892ca78eeddd9d6b629050fea432979ddd321)
3. [mmc: core: Remove deprecated mmc_suspend|resume_host APIs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=3c0d22e8180b98eea412b84aa0f0c42c16159679)

Maybe you just need to back-port those patches to fix your problem. Or at least they will make it a bit simpler to fix it.

Comment: I do have these change. I even noticed that there is cancellation in B. The problem is that mmc_rescan is taking too long to complete and B is blocking at mmc_flush_scheduled_work because of this. Now There is client that comes at this stage that requests for mmc host (but unable to find since mmc is mid way through the suspend activity). The only way I can think of is avoiding suspend when mmc_rescan is going on.

Comment: Have you checked if this changed in [newest kernel](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/) sources? Sounds like a rough bug to me. I would recommend you to ask this at [linux-mmc](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-mmc) mailing list (without mentioning **A** and **B**, just real function names and detailed description of your actual issue).

Comment: I added **UPDATE** to my answer, please check if those commits help.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a mutex and use it whenever you have shared variable in your code, here is an implementation of mutex and conditions  functions in Linux kernel [Linux Mutexes and Conditions](http://www.kylheku.com/~kaz/lmc.html)

Comment: Yeah, it's basically a duplicate of Michael's answer. And the issue is not about shared variable, it's about synchronization. Anyway, the problem seems to be more complicated than that and it may be not really best solution to just lock some mutex in both functions. This way **B** will only **wait** for **A** to finish. Read comments to get the whole picture.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i did not get the whole picture as you said.